# How should I organise my plist?

Tags: ios, plist, swift

I'm creating a game where the player can unlock worlds, where they can unlock levels within those worlds, each levels has a highscore, and so on.

I was wondering in which way should I store this data?  I was originally thinking of making a number of separate plist files, but that seems like an approach which could end up spiralling out of control.

Has anyone approached this problem and come up with a decent solution?

Comment: You might want to post your question on the Game Development Stack Exchange site here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most apps like that store data in a SQLite3 database rather than property lists. I recommend this route instead—actual implementation/etc is off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

I think a good approach would be to save each world under a category, and saving the information for each world.
 For example:

```
<dict>
    <key>Worlds</key>
    <dict>
        <key>TheLand</key>
        <dict>
            <key>WorldIsUnlocked</key>
            <true/>
            <key>Highscore</key>
            <string>1304</string>
            <key>Levels</key>
            <array>
                <key>level1</key>
                <true/>
                <key>level2</key>
                <true/>
                <key>level3</key>
                <false/>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

This way, you can easily point to whatever piece of information you want.

E.g extracting the highscore of the world "The Land"  `Worlds -> TheLand -> Highscore`, will print out: `1304`.
Checking what levels are available within "The Land" `Worlds -> TheLand -> Levels`, will print out an array: `level1: true, level2: true, level3: false`.

On a side note, this question is more programming related and should therefor be asked over at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).